# Remote Desktop Unique Guid

Tags: c#, licensing, guid, remote-desktop

I am writing a licensing application that is specific to our product. It is not highly detailed and elaborate but it will work for our business.

The license ties the hardware (3 pieces I obtain in .net) with the workstation id that is passed as a option when the program is executed. So, workstation id XXX is authorized to run on computer YYYYY.

The only loophole that I've seen in it is that they can run the application several times over RDP when they are only licensed to run once. Typically they

How can I assign a license to prevent them from running the application from different sessions multiple time when they are licensed for less?

Since this is run on peer 2 peer networks, most of the time, I can't rely on checking the task manager to see what is running at the time the program starts.

Anyone have any suggestions on what I can track on an RDP connection to tie a license to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your goal correctly you want to prevent them running the app more often thatn licensed... and you write you already solved that except for the situation where the app is running on the same machine in different sessions...

IF so then you only need a mechanism to prevent starting the app a second time on the same machine (even in a different session)... you can use a global Mutex to achieve that... see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx

Bascially you create a named Mutex with `Global\` as the prefix of the name... if that Mutex already exists then the app is already running on this machine (in the same or a different session)... if you want only to prevent it running a second time in the same session you use `Local\` as the prefix...

Comment: +1 Global MutEx will prevent multiple instances of an application from running. See this documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f55ddskf.aspx

Comment: This is great information and answers half of my question, what do I tie the license to so when they open the application initially it can verify that session is licensed to get in?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand fully... you write in the question that you already tie the license to some HW specific values... you can convert those to a string and use them as part of the Mutex name for example... If I got it wrong then please explain in more detail...

Comment: I do tie it to the hardware and this works on peer2peer computers but if two different users log into an rdp session (as different users) the hardware isn't going to catch it since they both return the same hardware signatures. HW Signature + Workstation Id could be the same for two users in rdp and allow them in.

Comment: Then you need to provide more details... does your app use a DB ? does it access any server ? does it access the internet ?

Comment: We are currently using flat files from a legacy application, this would be running specifically on a server using rdp and they all have internet access, though I'm not sure I want to limit myself to checking a license over the internet everytime they access the application.

Comment: you can either do that or limit yourself to some ActiveDirectory/Domain attributes...